# Describing an act of "deep" bowing in English

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

Is there any way in English (noun or a verb or a phrase) to describe an act of "deep" bowing, when the "bower" brings his head down below his lumbar region but doesn't kneel down?

I am especially interested in the case of imperative, like:

> Please, (give a) _________________ to the king!

Comment: I honestly don't think English has a better way than "bow deeply", [which is a fairly common phrasing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bow_INF+deeply%2Cdeep+bow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cbow_INF%20deeply%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbowed%20deeply%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbowing%20deeply%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbow%20deeply%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbows%20deeply%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeep%20bow%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about "obeisance"?

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obeisance

It's not specifically a deep bow, but the meaning should be appropriate in this context.

I'm not sure if you will find a word in English that specifically means a deep bow, as this isn't typically something that is done in most English speaking cultures.

Comment: "this isn't typically something that is done in most English speaking cultures" - I see, but what if it's a book in English about some non-English speaking culture? Then this act must be described somehow. If not one word, then, perhaps, some phrase?

Comment: "but the meaning should be appropriate in this context" - How should it go in the form of a request? "Please, do your obeisance to him."? "Please, make your obeisance to him."? "Please, produce your obeisance to him."? I specifically mean the physical obeisance (the actual movement of a body), not the obeisance in the figurative sense.

Comment: I think it would be something like "show obeisance before the king", or "show obeisance to the king"

Comment: It's showing respect or deference by a physical gesture.

Comment: If it is "about some non-English speaking culture", then what would they call it? It may or may not translate. But unless you need to be specific, I would use something like "Bow deeply before the king." Also, one wouldn't use *please* with a command.

Comment: "about some non-English speaking culture" reminds me of something one of my Japanese friends told me many years ago - "You will never comprehend the myriad different ways to bow correctly... so much so you should never even try to." Rule for foreigners... In Japan, don't bow, ever. Better to not do it at all than get it wrong ;)

Comment: I'm not sure qualifying a bow as a deep bow would be particularly important to an English speaking audience. It would seem more natural to simply say "bow before your king". As has been mentioned, "please" wouldn't ordinarily be used in this situation.

Comment: What's the difference between "bow before the king" and "bow to the king"? Also, are you sure that "show obeisance before the king" will for sure imply a physical action of bowing? Could that phrase simply mean any other act of respect (for example, taking off the hat, bowing only the head, saying some words of respect, etc.), but not the act of body bowing?

Comment: From what I've read "obeisance" would ordinarily mean to bow, but it doesn't seem to imply any particular type of bow, other than it showing respect and deference. In that way I would say it differs from, for example, a common bow of the head, which might be more casual. It seems to be the closest word I can find. If you need something very specific, you'd probably have to appropriate a word from another language, but this wouldn't have common understanding to an English audience. Another option may be to simply say "bow deeply before your king", or "bow humbly before your king".